# Visual basic function for intermittent antibiotic dosing

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner in VB. I wrote a little program to simulate dosing regimens of antibiotics using some exponential equations and pharmacokinetic data.

The problem I have is that I want to display on a graph the following mathematical function:

[image: equation]

That simulates the  concentration variation at different intervals of time:

[image: Chart of concentration w.r.t. time]

Where:

- b(t) is the concentration at time t that will be plotted as Y axis, t is time (plotted on the x-axis).
- b(0) is the concentration at time 0 and it is a known variable.
- u(t-a1) is a function that has the value u(t-a1)=b(o) if t=a1 or 0 if t<>a1
- a1 is the time at which a next dose is given.
- alpha is the elimination rate constant, a variable that is known.

What I have so far:

```
Dim y, x As Double

For x = 0 To 24 Step 1

    For n As Double = 1 To 24 / tau

        y = (1 - test_condition(n * tau, x)) * css * Math.Exp(-ke * x) + test_condition(n * tau, x) * css * Math.Exp(-ke * (x - n * tau))

        Chart1.Series("Concentratie1").Points.AddXY(x, y)
    Next
Next
```

[image: Chart I get]

The test_condition:

```
if x=tau then test_condition= 1 else 0
```

It is close but I don't get an exponential decay after a dose ... don't know how to make that happen.

This works!! for tau (dosing interval) every 4 hours. Can it be rearranged somehow because the tau (dosing interval) will vary (sometimes 4 hours, sometimes every 6 hours)?:

```
    Dim y, x, y2, x2, y3, x3, y4, x4, x5, x6, y5, y6 As Double

    For x = 0 To tau Step 1

        y = exponential_decay(css, ke, x) + test_condition(tau, x) * (css - Val(mic))

        Chart1.Series("Bolus 1").Points.AddXY(x, y)

    Next

    For x2 = tau To 2 * tau Step 1

        y2 = exponential_decay(css, ke, x2 - tau) + test_condition(2 * tau, x2) * (css - Val(mic))

        Chart1.Series("Bolus 2").Points.AddXY(x2, y2)
    Next

    For x3 = 2 * tau To 3 * tau Step 1

        y3 = exponential_decay(css, ke, x3 - 2 * tau) + test_condition(3 * tau, x3) * (css - Val(mic))

        Chart1.Series("Bolus 3").Points.AddXY(x3, y3)
    Next

    For x4 = 3 * tau To 4 * tau Step 1

        y4 = exponential_decay(css, ke, x4 - 3 * tau) + test_condition(4 * tau, x4) * (css - Val(mic))

        Chart1.Series("Bolus 4").Points.AddXY(x4, y4)
    Next

    For x5 = 4 * tau To 5 * tau Step 1

        y5 = exponential_decay(css, ke, x5 - 4 * tau) + test_condition(5 * tau, x5) * (css - Val(mic))

        Chart1.Series("Bolus 4").Points.AddXY(x5, y5)
    Next

    For x6 = 5 * tau To 32 Step 1

        y6 = exponential_decay(css, ke, x6 - 5 * tau)

        Chart1.Series("Bolus 4").Points.AddXY(x6, y6)
    Next


End Sub
```

[image: finaltest]

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available for drawing charts in VB.NET, if that is what you're looking for. Or are you asking how to calculate the points to chart?

Comment: Yes I want to calculate the points on the chart using that function

Comment: I can calculate the points with pen and paper but I don’t know how to convert that into visual basic :) I have been trying for 5 days and no luck, it’s getting frustrating

Comment: A glance at the .net Math class wouldn't hurt. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netframework-4.8 All of this is available to vb.net when you `Imports System.Math` at the top of your code file.

Comment: @Mary, `Math` is a class and you generally don't import classes. The `System` namespace is already imported by default, so there's no need to import that. If you want to call a `Shared` method of the `Math` class, which is all it has, then you simply qualify it with the class name, e.g. `Math.Max`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, of course. I have at the top of my testing file. I don't remember why. Thanks.

Comment: Dim y, x As Double

        For x = 0 To 24 Step 1

            For n As Double = 1 To 24 / tau



                y = (1 - test_condition(n * tau, x)) * css * Math.Exp(-ke * x) + test_condition(n * tau, x) * css * Math.Exp(-ke * (x - n * tau))

                Chart1.Series("Concentratie1").Points.AddXY(x, y)
            Next
        Next

Comment: this is a far as I got. But it adds spikes in concentration and no exponential decay after each spike.

Comment: @Adrian Can you give us some realistic values for `tau`, `ke`, and `css` please?

Comment: Sure, tau is the time interval for the next dose lets say tau=4 hours. Ke is the elimination rate constant, lets say ke=0.472 and Css is the maxium concetration of antibiotic , lets say Css= 40 mg/L

Comment: So as an example After the first dose the concentration at t=0 is 40 mg/L. After that there is an exponential decay, but after tau=4 hours we give another dose that spikes the concentration at css= 40 mg/L. After that the decay takes over , and after another 4 hours (t=2*tau) we give another dose that spikes up the concentration. Is it clear enough?

Comment: I think the secret is to make x (time) reset after x=tau so the decay will occur. But if in the For statement I make if x=tau then x=0 , I get an infinite loop ..

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem:
this function f relates time (t) to dosing interval (tau)

```
Private Function f(ByVal t As Double, ByVal tau As Double)
    Dim n As Integer

    For n = 0 To 24 / tau


        If t = n * tau Then
            f = n * tau
        ElseIf t < tau Then
            f = 0
        ElseIf t > n * tau And t < (n + 1) * tau Then
            f = n * tau
        ElseIf t >= (n + 1) * tau Then
            f = n * tau

        End If
    Next
End Function
```

And this is what I draw on the chart:

```
For x = 0 To 36 Step 0.5


        y = exponential_decay(css, ke, x - f(x, tau))




        Chart1.Series("Intermitent Dosage").Points.AddXY(x, y)
    Next
```